# TextureView: flicker effect when MediaPlayer setSurface

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I'm using `TextureView` with `MediaPlayer` as an element inside `ListView`. When user scrolls down/up and video disappears 
from the screen I’d like to continue playing it somewhere, let’s say right bottom corner. 
I'm using same `TextureView`, just extract it from list item and add to main layout. `MediaPlayer` also same.
So that `TextureView` is destroyed and recreated.

The issue is - when I set surface to player, scrolling freezes on half of second.
any help appreciated.

My `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
   int height) {

    Surface s = new Surface(surface);
    mPlayer.setSurface(s);
}
```

Comment: Have you done a method profiling trace to see where that half-second is going?

Comment: `MediaPlayer._setVideoSurface()` takes 272.5 ms

Answer (score -1):

MediaPlayer API is slow on some devices, you should not use it for your situation.

You should use the Ijkplayer ([IjkPlayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)) instead.